# Data Source and Custom Markers for Android Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am currently trying to build a yelp-like app as a personal project, and I plan to use the Google Maps API + Map Utils to help me, but I have two quick questions.

The first is why can't I change the background color of my custom marker?  Every time I try, the background is still the default white.
Here is my code:

```
  IconGenerator tc = new IconGenerator(this);

    Bitmap bmp = tc.makeIcon("1");
    tc.setColor(IconGenerator.STYLE_RED);



    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(38.681512, -90.248927))
            .title("San Francisco")

            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
```

My next question is how can I not hard code the text inside the markers?  What I'm trying to say is how can I program my app so that I don't have to hard code every marker because I don't want to have 100 different entries that all simply do the same thing, but just have different icon titles (i.e. numbers on the markers, like Yelp does in their app) and different slightly descriptions (also see Yelp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first is why can't I change the background color of my custom marker? Every time I try, the background is still the default white.

I see nothing in your code that sets the background. Hence, I would expect that your background will not change. A quick glance at the `IconGenerator` JavaDocs turns up [a `setBackground()` method](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html#setBackground%28Drawable%29) that may do what you need.

> My next question is how can I not hard code the text inside the markers?

Well, the text has to come from somewhere. It is presumably the same "somewhere" that the locations are coming from. That could be a database, or a file, or the results of a Web service call, or whatever.

So, for example, if you are getting the data from a Web service, you would iterate over the Web service response (e.g., array of objects parsed from JSON) and call `addMarker()` for each. Do bear in mind, though, that `addMarker()` needs to be called on the main application thread, and doing 100 of those at one time may freeze your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding customization of info windows.  You can [look at the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows).

I went ahead and got a simple example working for this.

Code to set up the `InfoWindowAdapter`:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);

                TextView tLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);

                TextView tSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.population);

                tLocation.setText(arg0.getTitle());

                tSnippet.setText(arg0.getSnippet());

                return v;

            }
        });
```

customlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:textColor="#D3649F"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:textColor="#D3649F"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image: custom InfoWindowAdapter]